# How to retrieve title with getElement

Tags: excel, vba

How can I retrieve the title in below code?
The class name is not unique, every row in the table is has the class name 'rf-dt-c'.

I tried with

```
objIE.document.getElementByID("docTypeForm:documentTB1:0:j_idt250").innerText
```

This is how the code on the site looks:

```
<td class="rf-dt-c" id="docTypeForm:documentTB1:0:j_idt250">
   <a href="url">TITLE</a>
```

code in the macro:

```
    For iRow = 0 To 20
        TableName = "docTypeForm:documentTbl:" & iRow & ":j_idt250"
        naming = obJIE.document.getElementByID("TableName").innerText
        MsgBox naming
        On Error GoTo DownloadFiles
        Set allLinks = obJIE.document.getElementByID(TableName).getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Comment: What happens with your attempt?

Comment: I get an error object required, I added the example on how it is now in the macro. If I remove the line from naming it works fine

Comment: Break the code up into sections and see what is missing, so objIE, objIE.Document etc and check your getElement, returns anything

Comment: Ah I see now when copying what went wrong... I have table name between "" Nevermind

Comment: I think you have a typo `docTypeForm:documentTB1:0:j_idt250` and `"docTypeForm:documentTbl:" & iRow & ":j_idt250"` TB1 and Tbl?